# Website Monitoring of Tor Onion Services

Tags: monitoring, nagios, website, alerts, tor

How can I monitor the uptime of my website's tor hidden service endpoint so I get an immediate notification if it goes offline? Bonus points for fancy monthly/yearly uptime reports.

I'd like to make my website accessible over a tor onion service so it's securely accessible to tor users. I'll probably rarely access my site over its `.onion` address, so it's especially important that I have monitoring software in-place to notify me if/when the site becomes inaccessible over Tor.

My entire infrastructure consists of exactly 1 server. It doesn't make sense to have the monitoring software run on the same server it's monitoring, so I currently use a SaaS service for monitoring my websites (pingdom/statuscake/cula/UptimeRobot/better uptime/etc).

How can I monitor my onion service so I receive an alert if it goes down? Are there any popular monitoring SaaS tools that support monitoring websites that are run as tor onion services?

Comment: See also https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/21715/website-monitoring-of-tor-onion-services/21716#21716

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any uptime SaaS providers that support monitoring websites on their onion service endpoints.

### cron

Until that day comes (as it's hard to think of a reason why any admins *shouldn't* make their websites accessible at a `.onion` address--which benefits the privacy of their visitors), a simple solution is just to spin up a small micro sever (such as the "always free" server in google's cloud) that does a simple curl over tor every 1 minute and sends an email alert if curl exits non-zero.

For example, if you want to monitor [torproject.org's onion service](https://onion.torproject.org/) (qrmfuxwgyzk5jdjz.onion):

```
user@disp9739:~$ curl -IL --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 http://qrmfuxwgyzk5jdjz.onion/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2020 15:16:44 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Location: index.html.en
Vary: negotiate,accept-language,Accept-Encoding
TCN: choice
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Xss-Protection: 1
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Nov 2020 15:12:24 GMT
ETag: "3cec-5b3fe74ab4600"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 15596
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Fri, 13 Nov 2020 16:16:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en

user@disp9739:~$
```

If you're running debian, then you can execute the following commands to create a simple cron job that will monitor your website:

```
sudo apt-get install tor curl mailutils
cat > /etc/cron.d/tor-hidden-service-monitoring <<'EOF'
* * * * * root url='http://qrmfuxwgyzk5jdjz.onion/'; curl -IL --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 "${url}" || echo "Unable to access ${url}" | mail -s "ALERT: hidden service inaccessible" youremail@example.com
EOF
```

The above commands will install `tor`, `curl`, and the `mail` command and create a simple cron job that will attempt to access `http://qrmfuxwgyzk5jdjz.onion/` every `1 minute` and email `youremail@example.com` if it fails.

### mon

To reduce false-positive email alerts, you could use `mon` to only trigger an alert after multiple consecutive queries fail.

```
sudo apt-get install tor torsocks mon

cat > /usr/lib/mon/mon.d/torsocks_http.monitor <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# File:    torsocks_http.monitor
# Version: 0.1
# Purpose: Wraps the http.monitor script with torsocks to monitor .onion sites
#  https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/monitoring-tor-onion-websites-uptime-alerts
# Authors: Michael Altfield <michael@michaelaltfield.net>
# Created: 2021-03-12
# Updated: 2021-03-12
################################################################################
 
export DIR_PATH=`dirname ${0}`
exec /usr/bin/torsocks --isolate ${DIR_PATH}/http.monitor -t 60 "$@"
 
EOF

hostgroup torproject_onion qrmfuxwgyzk5jdjz.onion
 
watch torproject_onion
        service http
                interval 5m
                monitor torsocks_http.monitor
                period 
                        alertafter 10
                        alertevery 1h strict
                        alert mail.alert youremail@example.com
                        upalert mail.alert youremail@example.com

systemctl restart mon.service
```

### Tor2Web

Finally, you can also use Tor2Web to create a clearnet proxy to your .onion site, then point your existing uptime monitoring IaaS tool at it.

- https://github.com/tor2web/Tor2web

## Source

The above solutions were originally published in the following article titled [Monitoring Tor .onion Websites (uptime alerts)](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2021/03/12/monitoring-tor-onion-websites-uptime-alerts/)

- https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2021/03/12/monitoring-tor-onion-websites-uptime-alerts/